# can not read character from user

Tags: c, scanf

here in this code i am creating a binary tree until user wants number of nodes.
but while getting input from user it fails somewhere..

```
   struct node *createTree(struct node *root)
{
  int n;
  char ch;
  struct node *t1;
  t1=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  printf("Enter Element\n");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  if(root==NULL)
    {
  t1->data=n;
  t1->left=NULL;
  t1->right=NULL;
  root=t1;
    } 

  printf("do you want to add node at left?\n");
```

this is not working properly

scanf("%c",&ch);

```
  if(ch=='y')
    {
      t1->left=createTree(t1->left);

    }


   printf("do you want to add node at right?\n");
   scanf("%c",&ch);

   if(ch=='y')
    {
      t1->right=createTree(t1->right);

    }




  return root;



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
printf("do you want to add node at right??!\n");
scanf("%c",&ch);
while (getchar()!='\n');  //<-- eat up trailing newline chars - Reads all characters of the line until the end of line is found.
```

When you press enter after entering a keyboard input - there stays in the buffer a trailing newline character which the next call on `scanf` reads.

Comment: but why? whats reason behind this?

Comment: @Kapil - you hit the <kbd>enter</kbd> key right? What does `enter` do on the console? It adds a newline character.

Comment: can we do it by flushing buffer?

Comment: @Kapil - [`fflush`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/) is not defined to be called on input streams.

Comment: Yes, encountered the same problem, thx for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to just give one space before %c in scanf

```
scanf(" %c",&ch);
```

This is because after giving the input we pressed enter that enter is stored in buffer and this read again by our program, some time we clear we flush our input/output buffer you can check in Linux `fflush()`I think so is the function, there is lots of way but this is the easiest way that I know.
Hope useful for you.